# Acid catalyst choice on reaction of carbonyl group and O/N nucleophiles

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

For oxygen nucleophiles, e.g. $\ce{ROH}$, when reacting with a carbonyl group to form acetal, the acid catalyst used is protonated alcohol.

for nitrogen nucleophiles, e.g. $\ce{RNH2/RR'NH}$, when reacting with a carbonyl group to form imine/enamine, the acid catalyst used is $\ce{NH4+}$ instead of protonated alcohol.

According to both reaction mechanisms, both catalysts are just acting as $\ce{H+}$ donators & acceptors, so why 2 different acid catalysts need to be used? Can't I use protonated alcohol all the time?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that NH4+ is the preferred catalyst? I find Ti(IV) species such at Ti(OiPr)4 the most effective.

Comment: @Waylander from 'Organic chemistry as a 2nd language 2nd semester', it told me ammonium ion is generally used as the catalyst. And sorry that I am just a beginner, when I look up the structure of Ti(OiPr)4 in Google, I don't know where is the ionizable proton.

Comment: [Titanium(IV) is a Lewis acids](https://doi.org/10.1002/9783527618309.ch15).

Comment: @234ff You need a better textbook

Comment: Seems all my talking under earlier question was in vain...

Comment: @Mithoron Yea sorry since the book always tell me that 'we generally use ... as the catalyst' without any explanation why it is 'generally' when C=O bond is attacked by nucleophiles. When I search it online I got online seems no one uses them, so I am so confused.